# Slow or stacking file.choose() in R

Tags: r

If I have more data loaded in R I'm having difficulties with opening and choosing new file via `file.choose()` and later upload via `read.csv()`, but I would not get to that point since the file.choose function stacks and the R "crushes" and reports something like "unidentified error occurred and that the R must restart".

I'm using **RStudio** and running this on Windows 7. The hardware is up to date.

Could someone point me on why this is happing and what would be a remedy against this. Are there other options to select file? I know I can insert the path right into the read.csv command, but the (file is different every time).

EDIT:

The error just happened again. I can not reproduce the error so it happens rather only with high likelihood if the conditions for it are met.

The error reads as: **R Session Aborted.R encountered fatal error. The session was terminated**. And in window: **"Start New Session"**.

EDIT 2:

I would just rephrase my question. The question is whether there is other option like command or package that deals with choosing a file. [file.choose()]

The error can not be reproduced and hence I can not expect someone gives reasonable comment on this. But if this occurred someone in the past and solved it, I would like to hear about it. Thanks.

EDIT 3: Further to the error. I have spotted just now sentence in red in Console: `Error: Unable to provide connection with R`

Comment: Can you show a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Also, try to reproduce the issue in R instead of RStudio.

Comment: I will now work solely only under R itself and see how it goes. Many thanks.

Comment: @Max, well, there is also `choose.files()`; it's not identical, but similar.

Comment: I will try. It may solve the ongoing issue. Thanks.